# How to do indexing in Solr

Tags: solr

I am quite new to the Solr. I need to know how the indexing is done in Solr.Where index file is stored. Whether the only key is stored or the value is also stored in the index file . How we retrive the value from the index file. Please help

Comment: I agree with the answer provided, please start with the Solr Tutorial - http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html and reading through the Solr Wiki.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to start with reading the [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/)